# Difference between cv::subtract and operator - in cv::Mat OpenCV

Tags: computer-vision, opencv, c++

What's the difference between cv::subtract and operator - in OpenCV?

```
Mat original = imread...;
Mat smoothed, difference, result;
```

smoothed - original image processed with Convolution with Gaussian kernel;

1)

```
difference = original - smoothed;
```

2)

```
cv::subtract(smoothed, original, difference);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Check this link](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void%20subtract(InputArray%20src1,%20InputArray%20src2,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20mask,%20int%20dtype), both are same.

[image: subtract operation]